# Using TableAdapter to Update Database Table with a DataTable

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I can correctly update a SQL database table with a `datatable` as follows:

```
Dim resultsDataTable As New DataTable()
Dim dtpHExportDataTable As New DataTable()
Dim cnString As String = <<<ConnectionString>>>
Using cnSQL1 As New SqlConnection
    cnSQL1.ConnectionString = cnString
        Using adapter1 = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT SampleNo, Results, Complete_Date, Dex_Row_Id " & "FROM LIMS.dbo.Analytical_Sample_Log_ResultsInfo", cnSQL1)
        Dim builder1 As New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter1)
        adapter1.UpdateCommand = builder1.GetUpdateCommand()
        Using New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter1)
            adapter1.Fill(resultsDataTable)
            resultsDataTable.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {resultsDataTable.Columns("Dex_Row_Id")}
            dtpHExportDataTable = resultsDataTable.Clone()
            AddResultsRow(dtpHExportDataTable, 13581, "4.4", "2015-01-01", 45598)
            AddResultsRow(dtpHExportDataTable, 13590, "5.5", "2015-01-01", 45618)
            AddResultsRow(dtpHExportDataTable, 13604, "6.6", "2015-01-01", 45655)
            resultsDataTable.Merge(dtpHExportDataTable)
             ShowResult(resultsDataTable)   ‘looks perfect
            adapter1.Update(resultsDataTable)    ‘database table IS updated correctly
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

However, when I expand the above code to my spreadsheet workbook page application, the `resultsDataTable` (shown by the `DevExpress` ShowResult(resultsDataTable)) displays the correct information using the code above as well as the code below.  But the database table is not updated using the code below:

```
Dim worksheet As Worksheet = SpreadsheetControl.Document.Worksheets.ActiveWorksheet
    Dim range As Range = worksheet.Selection
    Dim rangeHasHeaders As Boolean = True
    ' Create a data table with column names obtained from the first row in a range if it has headers.
    ' Column data types are obtained from cell value types of cells in the first data row of the worksheet range.
    Dim resultsDataTable As New DataTable()
    Dim dtpHExportDataTable As DataTable = worksheet.CreateDataTable(range, rangeHasHeaders)
    Dim cnString As String = "<<<ConnectionString>>>"
    Using cnSQL1 As New SqlConnection
        cnSQL1.ConnectionString = cnString           
    Using adapter1 = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT SampleNo, Results, Complete_Date, Dex_Row_Id " & "FROM LIMS.dbo.Analytical_Sample_Log_ResultsInfo", cnSQL1)
        Dim builder1 As New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter1)
        adapter1.UpdateCommand = builder1.GetUpdateCommand()
        Using New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter1)
          adapter1.Fill(resultsDataTable)
          resultsDataTable.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {resultsDataTable.Columns("Dex_Row_Id")}
           dtpHExportDataTable = resultsDataTable.Clone() 
            Dim exporter As DataTableExporter = worksheet.CreateDataTableExporter(range, dtpHExportDataTable, rangeHasHeaders) 
            ' Perform the export.
            exporter.Export()
            resultsDataTable.Merge(dtpHExportDataTable)
                      ShowResult(resultsDataTable)   ‘looks perfect
            adapter1.Update(resultsDataTable) )   ‘database table is NOT updated
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: i'm not sure what does the `worksheet.CreateDataTableExporter` do, but may be it use original DataRow version so it does not see changes. Try to export the data after `adapter1.Update`.

Comment: agent, the worksheet.CreateDataTableExporter is a DevExpress.com extension that obtains data from the specified range from the spreadsheet, It skips the header row, if required, and populates the specified data table.   Trying to export the data after adapter1.Update did not work.

Comment: I guess the Merge()  doesn't set the rowstate of the merged rows to added ... so there are no changes in your resultsDataTable and your Update() does nothing ...

Answer (score 0):

Supposed your codes for updating Database was working. And accompanying with export updating was not processed.

Then the problem is after exposing to another process. Update do not undergone.

so you could do it like this.

```
    Using adapter1 = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT SampleNo, Results, Complete_Date, Dex_Row_Id " & "FROM LIMS.dbo.Analytical_Sample_Log_ResultsInfo", cnSQL1)
    Dim builder1 As New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter1)
    adapter1.UpdateCommand = builder1.GetUpdateCommand()
    Using New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter1)
      adapter1.Fill(resultsDataTable)
      resultsDataTable.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {resultsDataTable.Columns("Dex_Row_Id")}
       dtpHExportDataTable = resultsDataTable.Clone() 

        resultsDataTable.Merge(dtpHExportDataTable)
                  ShowResult(resultsDataTable)  
        adapter1.Update(resultsDataTable)  

        Dim exporter As DataTableExporter = worksheet.CreateDataTableExporter(range, dtpHExportDataTable, rangeHasHeaders) 
        ' Perform the export.
        exporter.Export())

    End Using
```

Comment: this updates correctly in under one second for 2,500 rows.  I have passed the datatable as a parameter in a stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

I ended up passing the datatable as a parameter in a stored procedure.

```
-- Create User-defined Table Type

USE LIMS
GO

-- Create the data type
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[resultTable] AS TABLE 
(
[SampleNo]      [int]           NOT NULL,
[PAprojid]      [nchar]     (10)    NULL,
[PAprojName]        [nchar]     (100)   NULL,
[STMTNAME]      [nchar]     (85)    NULL,
[DateAndTime]       [date]          NULL,
[TestId1a]      [nchar]     (3) NULL,
[TestType1a]        [nvarchar]  (30)    NULL,
[Facility1a]        [nchar]     (80)    NULL,
[Results]       [nchar]     (10)    NULL,
[AUnits1]       [nchar]     (15)    NULL,
[SampleDate1a]  [date]          NULL,
[Complete_Date]     [date]          NULL,
[Comments1a]        [nchar]     (100)   NULL,
[Dex_Row_Id]        [int]           NOT NULL

PRIMARY KEY (Dex_Row_Id)
)
GO

USE [LIMS]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Update_TestResults]
@tblResults resultTable READONLY
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

MERGE INTO LIMS.dbo.Analytical_Sample_Log_ResultsInfo P
USING @tblResults S
ON P.Dex_Row_Id = S.Dex_Row_Id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET P.Results = S.Results;
END

  For Each row As DataRow In resultsDataTable1.Rows
                row.SetModified()
            Next

            resultsDataTable1.Merge(dtTSSExportDataTable)

            Using updateCommand As New SqlCommand("usp_Update_TestResults")
                updateCommand.Connection = cnSQL1
                updateCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tblResults", resultsDataTable1)
                cnSQL1.Open()
                updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cnSQL1.Close()
            End Using
```